# Why does my variable suddenly stop counting after the first loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a program that counts the amount of letters in a word. Everything seems to work fine except for the fact that my variable used for counting the number of letters (numberOfLetters) suddenly stops counting after the first loop. Here is my code:

```
import random
# Choosing a random word
with open("Random Words.txt", "r") as file:
    allText = file.read()
    allWords = list(map(str, allText.split('\n')))
    chosenWord = random.choice(allWords)
# Resetting variables
correctLetters = []
incorrectLetters = []
hiddenWord = []

numberOfLetters = 0

for i in range(12):  # Loop 12 times
    print(numberOfLetters)
    for letter in chosenWord:  # Loop once for every letter in the word
        numberOfLetters = numberOfLetters + 1  # Count the number of letters in the word

        if ''.join(correctLetters) in chosenWord:  # If a letter is guessed, show it. Otherwise, censor it.
            hiddenWord.append(chosenWord[numberOfLetters])
        else:
            hiddenWord.append('_')
        print(hiddenWord)
        hiddenWord = []
    userGuess = input('Guess a letter:')
    if userGuess in chosenWord:  # If the user guesses a letter correctly, we'll add it to the list of letters guessed
        correctLetters.append(userGuess)
        print(userGuess)
    else:
        incorrectLetters.append(userGuess)
#    print(hiddenWord)

print('Chosen word:' + chosenWord)
# UserGuess = input('\n')
print('Number of letters:')
print(numberOfLetters)
print('Correct letters:')
print(correctLetters)
print('Incorrect letters:')
print(incorrectLetters)
```

Output:

```
0
['b']
['u']
['n']
['d']
['a']
['n']
['t']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dr Hani Attar\PycharmProjects\Hangman\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    hiddenWord.append(chosenWord[numberOfLetters])
IndexError: string index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You wrote =+ 1, it is += 1 . =+1 means that you are assigning the value 1 to your variable at each loop, hence all these ones

Comment: @robinood I tried that, this is the output:
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: `numberOfLetters = numberOfLetters + 1`?

Comment: @BluBalloon where is this error? Is there still some code after   numberOfLetters += 1 ? Because I don't see where it could be in the code you gave us

Comment: @BluBalloon are you sure you tried what robinood said? `numberOfLetters += 1`?

Comment: @Stranger Yes. The problem might be somewhere in the rest of the code, I'll edit my post with the full code

Comment: Why read the entire file in to memory and split on `\n'`? `all_words = list(file)` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

String indexing is 0-based. But your code is treating it as 1-based. Note how in your sample output the `'a'` in the chosen word `'abundant'` is never printed -- you started with index 1.

`chosenWord[numberOfLetters]` will fail when `numberOfLetters == len(chosenWord)` -- which it will do in the final pass through the loop `for letter in chosenWord:`

One thing you could do is to use `chosenWord[numberOfLetters-1]` and include the line

```
numberOfLetters = 0
```

at the beginning of the for-loop. Otherwise you will have another string index out of range error in the second pass through the loop.

The for-loop itself seems unmotivated. Why assume that the user will make exactly 12 guesses? It would make more sense to use a while-loop. Loop while there are still letters to guess.

Comment: Below which for-loop do I put the `numberOfLetters = 0`? When I put it below `for i in range(12):` the number stays at zero, and when I put it below `for letter in chosenWord` it gives me the same error. Also I wrote exactly 12 loops as the original idea was to have exactly 12 guesses to guess the word.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was thinking about after the `for i in range(12)`. If you want to use `numberOfLetters` as an index into `chosenWord` then you can't let it get too big. You probably need to rethink your approach. What is the point of `hiddenWord.append(chosenWord[numberOfLetters])` anyway? Shouldn't it be a correct guess that you append? Also, what is the point of `''.join(correctLetters) in chosenWord`? Don't you already know that the correct letters are correct? Furthermore, that isn't testing if everything in `correctLetters` lie in the chosen word. Instead it is testing if it is a substring.

Comment: My approach was to scan every letter and print either '_' or the letter based on whether the user guessed the letter before or not. What do you suggest is a better way to only reveal the letters that the user has guessed?